# Time complexity of an algorithm that finds a "Star" among an array of people

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I ran across a problem that asked to find a star among an array of normal people. The definition of a star is "someone who knows no one, but everyone knows them". The input is an array of n persons, and the elementary test you can do is ask a person i "do you know person j" to which they reply "true" if they know him and false if not. Asking the minimum amount of questions.

The best solution for worst case scenario I found for this algorithm is O(nlog) (you ask a person if they know the person after them i+1,if they do, you remove them from being a potential star,if not, you remove i+1 from being a potential star, with each run through the array, I can half the number of potential stars) But the excerice said "prove it can be done in O(n) in the worst case scenario

Answer (score 3):

> The definition of a star is "someone who knows no one, but everyone knows them

By that definition, there can be at most one "star" in the group of people. If there was more than one star, then they both would have to know the other, or the other would not be a star, but then they themselves are no stars.

Thus, there are two sub-problems.

1. Find potential stars.

If there is more than one such person, there is no star; if there is exactly one such person:

2. Check whether everybody else knows that person.

The first part can be done with your proposed algorithm. Regardless of whether you ask whether A knows B, then whether C knows D etc., or if you then ask whether the "winner" of A or B knows C and so on: since you remove one "candidate" each time you ask, you will need at most O(n) steps, not O(nlogn). After that, you have a single potential star left, and can do the second step, which is a simple loop over all the other persons in the group.

Time-complexity for both steps is O(n) for a total of (still) O(n).